# row_overflow data was not converting to in_row data after altering or updating the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was learning about allocation units in Sql server and came to know about 3 types

- In_row_data LOB_DATA
- (Large object (LOB) data).
- Row-overflow data.

  ```
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE
       TABLE_NAME='TEST_ALLOCATION_UNITS')

   DROP TABLE TEST_ALLOCATION_UNITS
  CREATE TABLE TEST_ALLOCATION_UNITS(
   TEST_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,NAME VARCHAR(4000)
   ,NAME1 VARCHAR(5000)
   )
   GO

  INSERT INTO TEST_ALLOCATION_UNITS (NAME,NAME1) VALUES ('APPLE','BANANA')
  GO 500
  ```

  I had inserted 500 records in it

No i had ran the code and i got the result like this

```
select s.type_desc before_alter from sys.allocation_units s 
join sys.partitions p on p.partition_id=s.container_id 
where p.object_id=object_id('test_allocation_units')
```

[image]

Now I alter the table and reduced the both column size to 50 bytes each and again ran the above select statement

```
alter table test_allocation_units alter column name varchar(50)
alter table test_allocation_units alter column name1 varchar(50)

select s.type_desc from sys.allocation_units s 
join sys.partitions p on p.partition_id=s.container_id
where p.object_id=object_id('test_allocation_units')
```

[image]

**Question**

As per my understanding before altering of a table the *combined size of the columns for that table was grater than 8 Kb hence the allocation type was both In_row_data and Row_overflow_data*.
But ***after alter statement, i.e. reduction of column size to 50 bytes each then also the alloction unit was still both In_row_data and Row_overflow_data***

please explain.

thanks in advance

***Scenario 2***

I tried with an empty table and run the following code

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEST_ALLOCATION_UNITS'
        )
    DROP TABLE TEST_ALLOCATION_UNITS

CREATE TABLE TEST_ALLOCATION_UNITS (
    TEST_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,NAME VARCHAR(4000)
    ,NAME1 VARCHAR(5000)
    )
GO

SELECT s.type_desc before_alter,s.total_pages,s.used_pages,s.data_pages
FROM sys.allocation_units s
JOIN sys.partitions p ON p.partition_id = s.container_id
WHERE p.object_id = object_id('test_allocation_units')

ALTER TABLE test_allocation_units
ALTER COLUMN NAME VARCHAR(50)

ALTER TABLE test_allocation_units
ALTER COLUMN name1 VARCHAR(50)

SELECT s.type_desc after_alter,s.total_pages,s.used_pages,s.data_pages
FROM sys.allocation_units s
JOIN sys.partitions p ON p.partition_id = s.container_id
WHERE p.object_id = object_id('test_allocation_units')
```

I didn't inserted any record in the table the results of the above script is shown in the figure

[image]

Please Advice why even after altering the column size the allocation unit was n't changed?

Comment: You may get better answers if you migrate this question to dba.stackexchange.com See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: How can i migrate this question to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site

Comment: Thanks friend @VladimirBaranov

Answer (score 1):

To get the data "reallocated" you must run this command:

`ALTER TABLE TEST_ALLOCATION_UNITS REBUILD`

REBUILD advices SQL Server to reallocate Datapages on a HEAP TABLE.

Comment: really? which version of sql server?

Comment: sql server 2012

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question

> row_overflow data was not converting to in_row data after altering or
>   updating the table

, the table never had row_overflow data to start with, so there is nothing to convert when you alter the column type.

---

Add few more columns to your query:

```
select 
    s.type_desc
    ,s.total_pages
    ,s.used_pages
    ,s.data_pages
from 
    sys.allocation_units s 
    join sys.partitions p on p.partition_id=s.container_id 
where 
    p.object_id=object_id('test_allocation_units')
```

You'll see that only `IN_ROW_DATA` has non-zero number of pages, while  `ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA` has 0 pages reserved and used.

---

In any case, when you store "banana" value in `varchar(5000)` column you are storing only 6 bytes per row (plus some overhead). So, changing this column type into `varchar(50)` doesn't change anything substantial in the data pages.

There would be a difference in the number of pages that the table occupies on the disk, if the column had `char(5000)` type and then changed into `char(50)`. When you store "banana" value in the `char(5000)` column, the value is right-padded with 4994 spaces to the declared length of the column, so here the declared size of the column has immediate impact.

Again, regardless, these spaces would be stored in-row. If you try to create a table with both `char(4000)` and `char(5000)` columns the creation would fail, because the maximum row size is 8060 bytes in SQL Server.

---

To see non-zero values for `ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA` you need to store long strings in `varchar` columns in your table. For example:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_ALLOCATION_UNITS (NAME,NAME1) VALUES 
(REPLICATE('APPLE', 800)
,REPLICATE('BANANA', 833))
GO 500
```

In this case we are trying to store 4000 bytes in `name` and 4998 bytes in `name1`, which is 8998 in total (plus some extra overhead), which is more than maximum 8060 bytes, so the value is pushed off-row.

---

I'd recommend to try to add/delete few rows with short and long strings and check how the output of the view changes. This should help you understand the view's results.

Comment: I agree with your explanation but can you look to the scenario 2

Comment: @Smart003, why do you ignore the first line of the answer where I'm saying "Add few more columns to your query: `total_pages, used_pages, data_pages`"? Please do this and show us the result. I expect that in your scenario 2 you'll get zeroes for all types of pages, because the table is empty. 0 `used_pages` for the `ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA` means that the table doesn't have such pages.

Comment: @Smart003, the fact that `sys.allocation_units` view returns a row with `ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA` type is not important. What important is the number of pages of this type in the table. And the view returns 0 number of such pages before and after you change the column type. Which means that in your examples there are **no** pages with `ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA` type. There were no such pages originally and there were no such pages after the change of the column type. Just as expected. I'd recommend to add/delete rows with short and long strings and check how the output of the view changes.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I got some questions
1. Even after altering of the columns does allocation units (type_desc) will change?
2. After altering columns reduced to less than 8kb will Sql server will change the type desc in allocation unit?

Comment: @Smart003, 1. I would expect that numbers in `total_pages, used_pages, data_pages` columns would change, not the `type_desc` itself. These numbers tell you how many pages of each type are in the table. 2. It may not happen automatically. If you had non-zero number of `ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA` pages before `ALTER`, you may need to rebuild the table to get rid of them. Experiment yourself. Fill the table with long strings and try to `ALTER` it.